# Can't connect microstrategy to redshift

Tags: microstrategy

I just downloaded `microstrategy 10.6.0` and want to connect to my redshift cluster. I've added data source and all information needed in the picture:

[image: Microstrategy add new data form]

but it keeps getting error :

[image]

The jdbc used is `com.microstrategy.jdbc.redshift.RedshiftDriver`
Any solution to connect to redshift data source? Thanks

Comment: same issue, did You found any solution?

Comment: not yet, I've posted on microstrategy community and email them, and still no replies

Comment: Just to confirm - windows version well work over ODBC (tested), but I try to connect Mac Version. Also send email them today.

Comment: finally - they build 10.7 version, and it start work

Comment: Thanks for the updates :)